# How to get two sibling elements to transition simultaneously?

Tags: html, css, transition

I have two elements in a `div`, an image that fades in and some text that changes color, but I am unable to get them to transition at the same time. In other words, the mouse can only be over one or the other.

I tried to put the properties in the `div` that contains them, but that did not help.

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LEpx4/1/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div id="selectors">
    <div id="omselector">
        <a href="stills.html">
        <img class="noglow" src="images/stills/oldcog.png" alt="Old Work!">
        <img class="glow" src="images/stills/oldcogglow.png" alt="Old Work">
        <p class="button">OLD WORK</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.button
{
    float: bottom;
    width: 350px;
    font-size: 20pt;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 0;
    top: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
    -moz-transition: color 1s;
    -o-transition: color 1s;
    transition: color 1s;
    z-index: 6:
}

.button:hover
{
    color: #0df400;
}

#omselector
{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 7;
}

.glow, .noglow
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
}
```

Comment: *I tried to put the properties in the div that contains them, but that did not help* - how so?

Comment: Well, I tried putting the color: property in the #omselector properties list and adding #omselector:hover {color: #color;} but that did not do change the color of the font in .button for me.

Comment: Here it is.  To hover the <p> element you have to be either left or right of the 250px img tag as well.  Also, my original post was missing a little CSS, but the fiddle is complete. http://jsfiddle.net/LEpx4/1/

Comment: Have you considered JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simultaneously change the styling of both elements on a mouse event, you can take advantage of the parent element's mouse event and use `#omselector` and its `:hover` pseudo class in the selectors.

For example:

```css
#omselector:hover .button {/*...*/}
#omselector:hover .glow, .noglow {/*...*/}
```

**See [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/soboaz/LEpx4/2/) based on your own.**

Answer (score 1):

[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALKhm/)

One thing to note is that, try to position the images and the text inside the `#omselector` so they both receive the hover event. (Notice this wouldn't work of you hover over from the left side.